# Inno Setup loop from A to Z

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to write a function that will check for the existence of a particular directory on each drive in turn, store the path where it is found as a variable and return true if it exists and false otherwise:

```
function IsDirPresent(): Boolean;
var
  chrDriveLetter: Char;
  strMyDir: String;
begin
  for chrDriveLetter := 'A' to 'Z' do
    begin
      if DirExists(chrDriveLetter + ':\MyDir') then
        strMyDirPath := chrDriveLetter + ':\MyDir'
    end;
  if strMyDirPath <> '' then
    Result := True;
end;
```

I get a Type mismatch error on my loop line when compiling this. I am struggling to work out what is wrong with the loop and haven't been able to find any information on how to correctly create a loop from A to Z in Inno Setup.

Comment: Note that accessing drive letters may have unintended results (such as causing floppy drive seek noises or re-mounting a network drive) and this sort of search is generally not encouraged.  It's usually best to discover the location using a registry lookup, or failing that to just ask the user to find it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop is valid for Pascal language because the `Char` type is ordinal and its range constants are of the same type, so I guess this is a specific limitation of the Pascal Script language notation. I don't know if there's some syntax workaround nor if the `Char` type is even allowed to be used for the loop control variable.

I can only provide you a workaround working with integer type loop control variable. It uses the `Ord` and `Chr` functions. The first returns the ordinal value of a char, the latter ASCII char from the ordinal value:

```
var
  C: Char;
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Ord('A') to Ord('Z') do
  begin
    C := Chr(I);
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly and has stopped me pulling my hair out!